# Query a recordset

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to work out how to move the $sql_pay_det query outside of the $sql_pay loop (so in effect query on $rs_pay_det rather than creating a new $rs_pay_det for each iteration of the loop)

At the moment my code looks like:

```
        //Get payroll transactions
        $sql_pay = 'SELECT Field1, DescriptionandURLlink, Field5, Amount, Field4, PeriodName FROM tblgltransactionspayroll WHERE CostCentreCode = "'.$cc.'" AND SubjectiveCode = "'.$subj.'" AND PeriodNo = "'.$month.'"';
        $rs_pay = mysql_query($sql_pay);
        $row_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay);

            while($row_pay = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay))
              {
                    $employee_name = $row_pay['Field1'];
                    $assign_no = $row_pay['DescriptionandURLlink'];
                    $pay_period = $row_pay['Field5'];
                    $mth_name = $row_pay['PeriodName'];
                    $amount = $row_pay['Amount'];
                    $total_amount = $total_amount + $amount;
                    $amount = my_number_format($amount, 2, ".", ",");

                    $sql_pay_det = 'SELECT ElementDesc, Amount, WTEWorked, WTEPaid, WTEContract, Payscale FROM tblpayrolldetail WHERE CostCentreCode = "'.$cc.'" AND SubjectiveCode = "'.$subj.'" AND AccountingPeriod = "'.$mth_name.'" AND EmployeeRef = "'.$assign_no.'"';
                    $rs_pay_det = mysql_query($sql_pay_det);
                    $row_pay_det = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay_det);

                while($row_pay_det = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay_det))
                {
                    $element_det = $row_pay_det['ElementDesc'];
                    $amount_det = $row_pay_det['Amount'];
                    $wte_worked = $row_pay_det['WTEWorked'];
                    $wte_paid = $row_pay_det['WTEPaid'];
                    $wte_cont = $row_pay_det['WTEContract'];
                    $payscale = $row_pay_det['Payscale'];

                    //Get band/point and annual salary where element is basic pay
                    if ($element_det =="3959#Basic Pay"){
                        $sql_payscale = 'SELECT txtPayscaleName, Salary FROM tblpayscalemapping WHERE txtPayscale = "'.$payscale.'"';
                        $rs_payscale = mysql_query($sql_payscale);
                        $row_payscale = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_payscale);

                        $grade = $row_payscale['txtPayscaleName'];
                        $salary = "£" . my_number_format($row_payscale['Salary'], 0, ".", ",");

                    }
                }
            }
```

I've tried doing this:

```
        //Get payroll transactions
        $sql_pay = 'SELECT Field1, DescriptionandURLlink, Field5, Amount, Field4, PeriodName FROM tblgltransactionspayroll WHERE CostCentreCode = "'.$cc.'" AND SubjectiveCode = "'.$subj.'" AND PeriodNo = "'.$month.'"';
        $rs_pay = mysql_query($sql_pay);
        $row_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay);

        //Get payroll detail recordset
        $sql_pay_det = 'SELECT ElementDesc, Amount, WTEWorked, WTEPaid, WTEContract, Payscale, EmployeeRef FROM tblpayrolldetail WHERE CostCentreCode = "'.$cc.'" AND SubjectiveCode = "'.$subj.'" AND AccountingPeriod = "'.$mth_name.'"';
        $rs_pay_det = mysql_query($sql_pay_det);

            while($row_pay = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay))
              {
                    $employee_name = $row_pay['Field1'];
                    $assign_no = $row_pay['DescriptionandURLlink'];
                    $pay_period = $row_pay['Field5'];
                    $mth_name = $row_pay['PeriodName'];
                    $amount = $row_pay['Amount'];
                    $total_amount = $total_amount + $amount;
                    $amount = my_number_format($amount, 2, ".", ",");

                    //Query $rs_pay_det
                    $sql_pay_det2 = 'SELECT ElementDesc, Amount, WTEWorked, WTEPaid, WTEContract, Payscale FROM ('.$sql_pay_det.') tpd WHERE EmployeeRef = "'.$assign_no.'"';
                    $rs_pay_det2 = mysql_query($sql_pay_det2);
                    $row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay_det2);

                while($row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay_det2))
                {
                    $element_det = $row_pay_det2['ElementDesc'];
                    $amount_det = $row_pay_det2['Amount'];
                    $wte_worked = $row_pay_det2['WTEWorked'];
                    $wte_paid = $row_pay_det2['WTEPaid'];
                    $wte_cont = $row_pay_det2['WTEContract'];
                    $payscale = $row_pay_det2['Payscale'];

                    //Get band/point and annual salary where element is basic pay
                    if ($element_det =="3959#Basic Pay"){
                        $sql_payscale = 'SELECT txtPayscaleName, Salary FROM tblpayscalemapping WHERE txtPayscale = "'.$payscale.'"';
                        $rs_payscale = mysql_query($sql_payscale);
                        $row_payscale = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_payscale);

                        $grade = $row_payscale['txtPayscaleName'];
                        $salary = "£" . my_number_format($row_payscale['Salary'], 0, ".", ",");

                    }
                }
            }
```

But I get an error on $row_pay_det2 saying that "mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Comment: use Join !! take a look at mysql tutorials !!

Comment: In `$row_pay_det2`, you have `"` around your table. remove it.

Comment: @Pankit - very helpful. What's the point of a forum if your advice is to read tutorials??

Comment: @GDB - thanks. I removed the " but still get the same error.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subquery` syntax (`... FROM "'.$rs_pay_det.'" ...`) is wrong.

According to the manual - [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual
> syntax is:
>
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...

Try changing to-

```
$sql_pay_det2 = 'SELECT ElementDesc, Amount, WTEWorked, WTEPaid, WTEContract, Payscale FROM ('.$sql_pay_det.') tpd WHERE EmployeeRef = "'.$assign_no.'"';
```

---

Edit - Issue #2

You are only getting the 2nd row in your data set as you have duplicate code (mysql_fetch_assoc() & mysql_fetch_array()) that [`moves the internal data pointer ahead`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) after the using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. So when you do `mysql_fetch_array()` you will get every row except the 1st row.

```
    //Get payroll transactions
    ...
    $row_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay);

    //Get payroll detail recordset
    ...

        while($row_pay = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay))
          {
                ...
                $row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay_det2);

            while($row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay_det2))
            {
                ...
                }
            }
        }
```

You need to remove - `$row_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay);` & `$row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay_det2);`

Comment: Thanks Sean. That fixed the error but it seems to be skipping the first result in each query - I'm expecting 6 names to be returned from tblgltransactionspayroll but I'm only getting the last 5 and for each name I'm expecting 2 results from tblpayrolldetail but I'm only getting the 2nd.

Comment: This is because you are using `$row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_pay_det2);` which gets the 1st row, so when you do `while($row_pay_det2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_pay_det2))` you will only get rows 2++. I have updated my answer with the 2 lines of code that need to be removed.